# Calculate the number of working day hours between two dates (e.g. 8:30 to 17:30 excluding weekends)

Tags: php, php-5.3

I need to calculate the number of working hours that have expired between two dates. Working hours are 08:30 to 17:30, Monday to Friday.

Here is what I have so far, can anybody see the flaws in my logic? I’m sure it could also be made much more compact and better.

The answers in the question which this is marked as a duplicate of give two different answers in php 5.3 and 5.4 I need it to be correct in both versions!

```
 /*You take your start date and calculate the rest time on this day (if it is a business day)
 You take your end date and calculate the time on this day and
 take the days in between and multiply them with your business hours (just those,   that are business days)
 Day start is 08:30 and day end is 17:30 so 9 hour working days*/

function biss_hours($start, $end){

   $startDate = new DateTime($start);
   $endDate = new DateTime($end);

   //Set the start and end dates to the start of the working day
   $startofday = clone $startDate;
   $startofday->setTime(8,30);
   $enddaystart = clone $endDate;
   $enddaystart->setTime(8,30);

   //get the rest time on start day in hours
   $t1 = $startofday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $t2 = $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $firstDayRest = calculate_hours($t1, $t2);

   //get the rest time on start day in hours
   $t3 = $enddaystart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $t4 = $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $lastDayRest = calculate_hours($t3, $t4);

   //Get the number of days between the two dates
   $daysBetween = getWeekdayDifference($start, $end);
   //multiply the days by the 9 working hours
   $hoursBetween = $daysBetween * 9;
   //add the rest times onto the number of working hours between the two dates.
   return $hoursBetween + $firstDayRest + $lastDayRest;

}


//returns the hours between two dates
function calculate_hours($t1, $t2){
   $t1 = StrToTime ($t1);
   $t2 = StrToTime ($t2);

   $diff = $t2 - $t1;
   $hours = $diff / ( 60 * 60 );

   return $hours;
}
//returns the number of days (excluding weekends) between two dates
function getWeekdayDifference($startDate, $endDate)
{
   $days = 0;

   $startDate = new DateTime($startDate);
   $endDate = new DateTime($endDate);

   while($startDate->diff($endDate)->days > 0) {
      $days += $startDate->format('N') < 6 ? 1 : 0;
      $startDate = $startDate->add(new \DateInterval("P1D"));
   }

   return $days;
}

$start = '2014-06-25 11:30';
$end = '2014-07-22 12:30';
echo $onHold = biss_hours($start, $end);
```

Comment: Are your start and end times guaranteed to represent whole days? Or would you ever need to know how many hours between say 3:30 on your start day and 4:15 on the end day?

Comment: I am unsure what problems you are having or do you just want to know if it can be done better?

Comment: I would defiantly need to know many hours between 3:30 on your start day and 4:15 on the end day. The start and end time could be any time within the working day.

Comment: The Problem is it does not calculate the hours correctly in all cases especially when its less than a day apart and I wouldn’t mind if it was done better.

Comment: The answers in the marked duplicate don’t work correctly, can please allow my question to be answered!!